# Scala - typesafe "case class" that has empty fields but doesn't use options

Tags: scala, data-structures, immutability

Let's think about continuously updating context. In my case I have quite a big function with tons of parameters that I pass around and they are initialized in later stages and used after that.

For example I don't know what IP I'm going to get from amazon on initialization of an instance, yet I know that the type I'm going to have is `IP` or `String`, same about stack and instance ID's.
Later I want to connect to this instance using some kind of protocol, so I'll use this parameter.

I could build a case class with all fields that are `Option`s, but in my case it's an overkill, because if I don't succeed raising an instance, I'll fail throwing an Exception instead of using an empty option. This would lead to tons of useless `Option.get`.

Now the question is: which kind of data structure could I use that's not an `Option`, can be easily copied (=> immutable) and in which I can declare the types of parameters but initialize them later?

Comment: How you're going to distinguish situation with the missing data? (e.g. no IP was assigned yet)

Comment: Throw an exception, I don't care. This should not happen.

Comment: "Throw an exception, I don't care" is pretty much the opposite of "type-safe" :)

Comment: OK, I understand. I either should give something a value in compile time, or if it may not have a value - this should be reflected in it's type. So maybe there is another solution to rolling a "state snowball" between functions, besides big amount of parameters?

Comment: Could you maybe explain with some example code how you intend to use this? It feels like there are two stages: a configuration stage and a runtime stage. In the configuration stage you are building your configuration (using defaults and external values), in the runtime stage you have gathered all you needed and can represent it as a case class.

Comment: A non-typesafe solution would be `Configuration(ip:IP = null, stack:String = null)`. Instead of option execeptions you would get null-pointers.

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, I understood that actually there is no way to do this with a single type. If the value is nonexistent at some stage, it shouldn't be in the type itself. That means that after every new piece of data I receive, I should create a new type with appended field. I can't think of easy way to do it in Scala (case classes are not extendable, tuples/HLists have no field names) and other approaches (`Option.get`, nulls, map) are quite the same, simply not type-safe. Now, which answer I should accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 options

1. Use immutable Map as a configuration object for your system, you have Options support out of the box there.
2. Define empty default values for your case class, so that you would not need to deal with Options

Comment: 1. But you loose types (the title requires typesafe solution)

Comment: In case of case class you don't have too:) In case of a Map I would say this is negligible, for the most parameters.

Comment: I thought about both of solutions. First is not type safe, second smells like java's nulls (yet in fact what I wan't to get is quite "nullish" behavior).

Comment: Perhaps a two-stage solution where you "build up" configuration in a `Map[String, Any]` before converting it to a case class using a [library (shameless plug)](https://github.com/themillhousegroup/sausagefactory). All the exceptions are then constrained to occurring at "conversion-time".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure I understood your point precisely, but I think one option would be that of mimicking the way config files are read, i.e. using a map String -> DataType.

You could construct a ''dictionary'' object that stores the const string names of your parameters, and inside such object you would also have a map ->String to the supertype of all your parameters.

```
object MyParameters {
  var values: Map[String, Any] = Map ()

  val ip = "IP"
  val stack = "STACK"
}

def myInitFunction = {
  import MyParameters._
  if (values.contains(ip)) doSomethingWith(values(ip):IpType)
}
```

If instead you want to also store the data type of each parameter you could have a double map inside the object, one from string to type and the other from string to value. You could also pre-define the types of your values by hardcoding them in the definition of the string -> type map. Since this is an object, you don't need to copy anything

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can take a look on different implementations of "type-safe builders" like [this one](http://blog.rafaelferreira.net/2008/07/type-safe-builder-pattern-in-scala.html), but all I've seen result in lots of boilerplate code.

Other good option is have custom map type with keys having type information, much like SBT does

```
  trait Key[T]

  trait TypeSafeMap {
    def apply(k: Key[T]): T
    def update(k: Key[T], v: T)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Option` fields as the external interface, you can use them internally, and write getters and setters that call `Option.get` as necessary:

```
case class C(xOpt: Option[Int] = None, yOpt: Option[String] = None) {
    def x = xOpt.get
    def setX(value: Int) = copy(xOpt=Some(value))
    def y = yOpt.get
    def setY(value: String) = copy(yOpt=Some(value))
}
```

So in the following example:

```
val c = C()
val c2 = c.setX(3)
val result = c2.x
```

`result` will be `3`, and the user of the class did not need to call `.get` or know about the underlying `Option`s.

```
val result2 = c2.y
```

will throw an exception, because `y` hasn't been set.

Answer (score 0):

I would represent this as two case classes, one for gathering up the potentially-invalid parameters, and another case class to represent a validated, has-all-the-paramteres-it-needs configuration.

E.g.:

```
// this has all the info that happens in a 'valid' case
case class ValidConfig(ip: String, stack: String)

// this has placeholders for potentially invalid case
case class GatheringConfig(ip: Option[String], stack: Option[String])
```

You then need a method that can convert the `GatheringConfig` into a `ValidConfig`, so that you can reference the fields you need directly, knowing that they are present. This method must validate the fields of a `GatheringConfig` instance, and only construct an instance of `ValidConfig` when all the necessary fields are present. This can be implemented in several ways, pick according to taste:

- using exceptions, e.g. `gatheringConfig.ip match { case None => throw new InvalidStateException() ... }`
- using `Either` or `Try` to indicate errors without an exception, allowing only the success case to attempt to construct a `ValidConfig`
- if you're feeling ambitious, an applicative functor for validation.

Bonus points if the only place in your codebase that can construct an instance of `ValidConfig` comes after validation is passed, ensuring all the necessary fields are present (through, e.g. visibility rules enforced by the compiler).